# constrOptim function with two constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to use constrOptim function with two given constraints in R but not able to figure out how to set up the problem.

For example, I need to minimise an objective function `cof(x)` with constraints `pi(x) > 0` and `pr(x) > 0`. How do I do this in R? This is just a hypothetical example. Do not worry about its structure, instead I am interested to know how to set this up in R.

Note: `cof(x)`, `pi(x)` and `pr(x)` are linear functions with x>0.

`cof(x)`, `pi(x)` and `pr(x)`functions results can be both negative and positive.

thanks!

My Task code is:

`objective <- function(x) {x1 <- x[1] cof(x1)   }`

`constraint1 <- function(x) {x1 <- x[1]   return(pi(x1)) }`

`constraint2 <- function(x) {   return(pr(x1)) }`

`combined <- function(x) {   return(list("objective" = objective(x1),             "constraint1" = constraint1(x1),               "constraint2" = constraint2(x1))) }`

`result <- constrOptim(c(0,0), fn = objective, gr = NULL,                       ui = rbind(1, 1), ci = c(0, 0))`

Comment: Which result do you get with the code you already have (assumed proper line breaks inserted)?

Comment: I try to find the optimal x to minimise the objective function subject to two constraints

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: I got this error: Error in constrOptim(c(0, 0), fn = objective, gr = NULL, ui = rbind(1,  : 
  initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region

Comment: If your contrains are function, i would advice to  directly use `optim` function and set the objective function to return `NA` if the contrains are not met. That is because the constraint functions might be complicated and not easy to invert to get the ROI. The result obtained from the optim function will be similar to the one obtained using constrOptim

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider an example, e. g. *pi(x) = 3*x-2* and *pr(x) = -x+9*. From the constraints *pi(x) > 0* and *pr(x) > 0* we get *3*x-2 > 0 ↔ x > 2/3* and *-x+9 > 0 ↔ x < 9*, so lower and upper bound are *2/3* and *9*, respectively. The constraint matrix `ui` shall contain one row for each constraint and one column for each function parameter, where there is a *1* for a *greater than* and a *-1* for a *less than* constraint, respectively. The constraint vector `ci` shall contain the right hand sides of the inequalities (where the parameter is on the left), negated for *less than*. So in this example case, `ui = rbind(1, -1)` and `ci = c(2/3, -9)`.
See also this [answer to *How to set limits using constrOptim in R?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27074/391835)